# Is there a way to create a name of a variable and have this change from a loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

Say that I have a for loop with index i, and I want to have a variable with a name that ends with the character(s) of the index number. Therefore, each time for loops, it will create a variable with a unique name. I want this variable to be a global variable, too. And then, I would want to use each of those variables later by calling var `name(i)` name of index. It would be okay if they were called some other way, too.

It could maybe be done with an array, but with this case, I end up with an array of arrays again, and I need a single array. I need to start with an array of arrays, too.

```
var arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];
var array = [];
for(i = 0; i < arrays.length; i ++)
  array[i] = arrays[i];
```

And I cannot simply use the reduce function because I want each of the arrays in my array of arrays to be a separate array.

```
var arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];
  arrays.reduce(function(a, b){
    return a.concat(b);
  }, []);
```

Note that the input array of arrays will be different each time the program runs and sometimes be jagged.

Comment: You can use `Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arrays)` to merge it into one array. (This is probably the easiest to me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question. You can create variables in the global scope using the syntax `window[varname]`

So if you want a seperate variable for each array in `arrays`, you could do this:

```
var arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];
for(i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++)
    window["array"+i] = arrays[i];
```

You could then access the arrays as `array0`, `array1`, etc.

Edit: fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5exfwne1/

Comment: Wow! That's cool!!  :) Is there a way to find how many array0, array1, array2, etc. there are without having to go back to the original array of arrays? If not, I have what I need. Thanks so much!!! :)

Comment: I know that if I went back to the original array of arrays I could use arrays.length

Answer (score 0):

I noticed varios syntax errors in your second declaration, however, it looks like what you intend to do is:

```
var arrays= [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];

  arrays.reduce(function(a, b){
    a = a.concat(b); return a;
  },[]); //outputs [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

**Array.prototype.reduce** needs to be initialized as an array by `arrays.reduce(function(a, b){},[])` the `[]` initialize it as array instead of 0. This function also needs to return something, in this case the concatenated array.

Comment: Thanks for noticing my extra line of code, my needing to use the empty array as start, and my needing to return a.concat(b);.